# Django OneToOneField not selected

Tags: django, forms, field

I'm developping in Django and I'm trying to do a form to edit some datas.

Here is my Model :

```
class Jewel(models.Model):
    ...
    goldColor = models.ForeignKey(GoldColor, related_name='jewels')
    bound = models.OneToOneField('self', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

An my form :

```
class JewelsManagementForm(forms.Form):
    goldColor = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=LABEL_GOLD_COLOR, queryset=GoldColor.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select())
    bound = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=LABEL_BOUND, queryset=Reference.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
    ...
```

But when I edit these datas, goldColor field is correctly assigned with previous value, but bound is not.
Is there a way to do that correctly ? Should I use another field type ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) to automatically create the form for your model.